# Remove string from string

Tags: android, string

```
String startTag = "<sessionid>";
String endTag = "</sessionid>";                                       
if (startTag.equalsIgnoreCase("<sessionid>") && 
   endTag.equalsIgnoreCase("</sessionid>"))
{
   int startLocation = strResponse.indexOf(startTag);
   int endLocation = strResponse.indexOf(endTag);
   Log.i("StartLocation", ""+startLocation);
   Log.i("EndLocation", ""+endLocation);
   String session_id =  strResponse.substring(startLocation, endLocation);
   ConstantData.session_id =session_id;
   Log.i("SessionId", ""+session_id);
}
```

I am getting `session_id = <sessionid>32423jhoijhoijh`; so I want to remove `<sessionid>`. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: try  String session_id =  strResponse.substring(startLocation+11, endLocation); here 11 is length of <sessionid>

Comment: exact duplicate of [How can I remove a part of a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5538271/how-can-i-remove-a-part-of-a-string)

Comment: Please grant the answer flag to the person who provided a suitable solution for you.

Answer (score 2):

`int startLocation = strResponse.indexOf(startTag) + string length of startTag`

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the first 11 letters or characters from the String:

```
String startTag = "<sessionid>";
String endTag = "</sessionid>";                                       
if (startTag.equalsIgnoreCase("<sessionid>") && 
   endTag.equalsIgnoreCase("</sessionid>"))
{
   int startLocation = strResponse.indexOf(startTag);
   int endLocation = strResponse.indexOf(endTag);
   Log.i("StartLocation", ""+startLocation);
   Log.i("EndLocation", ""+endLocation);
   String session_id =  strResponse.substring(startLocation, endLocation);
   session_id = session_id.substring(11, session_id.length());
   ConstantData.session_id =session_id;
   Log.i("SessionId", ""+session_id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take the length of `"<sessionid>"` as your startIndex instead of indexOf.

Answer (score 0):

One might try regular expressions too;

```
    String str = "<sessionid>ABCDEFGH</sessionid>";
    str = str.replaceFirst("<sessionid>(\\S+)</sessionid>", "$1");
```